# Golang работа с байтовыми массивами

Tags: golang

Хочу переписать вот такой код с си на го:

```
static void GOST_Kuz_X(const uint8_t *a, const uint8_t *b, uint8_t *c)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < BLOCK_SIZE; i++)
        c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
}
```

Не понимаю, на что заменить указатели на массивы байт. У меня получается такой код:

```
package main

const BlockSize = 16

func GostX(a, b, c []byte) {
    for i := 0; i < BlockSize; i++ {
        c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i]
    }
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы на языке го можно было работать с массивами байт просто, без лишнего кода, без преобразования массивов в слайсы и удобно. Как такое реализуется на этом языке?

В сишном коде функция `x-преобразование` принимает указатель на массив, который заполняет внутри себя, а в го функции обычно возвращают слайсы. Как лучше сделать работу с байтовыми массивами?

Answer (score 0):

Совершенно непонятно, чем вам не нравятся слайсы. Слайсы являются стандартной коллекцией в го.

Что же касается вашего случая, если константа не будет меняться, просто используйте указатели на массивы константного размера:

```golang
const BlockSize = 16

type Block [BlockSize]byte

func GostX(a, b, c *Block) {
    for i := 0; i < BlockSize; i++ {
        c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i]
    }
}
```